# ReadOnly ComboBox

Tags: java, javafx

I have a user interface, with buttons, textfields and comboboxes.
It depends on the user connection to make them editable or not.
With Fields it's easy, just :

```
setEditable(false);
```

But comboBox is a problem for me.

When I use:

```
setDisabled(true);
setOpacity(1.0);
```

The combobox is fully visible, not editable (editable in a comboBox means that you write your own text, it's automatically set to false), but the text in the combobox is grey.

Do you have an idea on how to make it not editable, and make it look like an editableComboBox. The text shall still be visible.

Comment: Why don't you use setEditable method of the ComboBox? Or did I not understand you?

Comment: @SoftwareGuy This is an editable combobox : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/figures/uiswing/components/EditableComboBoxMenuMetal2.png Basically, making it not editable just means that you can't write your own item in the combobox

Comment: Is'nt it [setRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setRenderer%28javax.swing.ListCellRenderer%29) ?

Comment: @PeterMmm Well, setRenderer would be great I suppose, but it's Swing, and I use JavaFX. Do you think I can mix the two APIs?

Comment: I always thought that Swing dropped the ball on this. The only components that supported a `true` setEditable() (i.e., read-only) were JTextComponents. I always had to roll my own for every other component.  I hope JavaFX took this into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want the ComboBox to be NOT editable but still look like how it usually looks like when it is editable. If so, you can use CSS in JavaFX to modify how the controls look like.

In case of ComboBox, it uses a TextField internally which also inherits TextInputControl's CSS, so you can modify the color and other look-and-feel of the text as described in JavaFX CSS Reference:

```
-fx-text-fill: black;
```

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#textinputcontrol

**UPDATE:**

I was able to put up a tiny sample app that uses CSS to set the background color the same as the editable combobox:

```
package cssstyling;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CssStyling extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500, Color.BLACK);

        ComboBox b = new ComboBox();
        b.setButtonCell(new ListCell());
        b.getButtonCell().setStyle("-fx-background-color: white;");
        b.setLayoutX(220);
        b.setLayoutY(20);
        root.getChildren().add(b);

        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX Scene Graph Demo");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

Hope it was useful!

Comment: Well, it was a great idea, but `comboBox.setStyle("-fx-text-fill;");` doesn't work, neither does `     clientPrefixCombo.setCellFactory(<ListView>() { @@@
                return new ListCell(){
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(final Object o, final boolean b) {
                        super.updateItem(o, b);    
                        setStyle("-fx-text-fill;");
                    }
                };

            });`

Comment: Yeah you understood very clearly what I wanted. But I may not have understood completely how you told me to deal with it. I didn't find how to access the TextField from the combobox.

Comment: unfortunately, i am at work so can't hack much.. but I am almost sure we have to use CSS. I will perhaps try and hack a bit when I get home. sorry ;(

Comment: Don't worry, I'm not in a hurry. Thanks anyway for your time.

Comment: @Fabinout I have posted some code. I hope it is useful for you.

Comment: Thank you again for your time. The probleme is that the combobox doesn't show the selected item anymore. I kinda forgot to explain this part of the problem... : /

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, I noticed that, but that can also be addressed using CSS. See this link for reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#combobox where it shows the heirarchy. You should set the CSS for the combo-box-popup and/or its child elements. The idea of the sample app was to build a starting point on how to play with css.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS documentation describes the pseudoclasses that a Node may have.  This includes the .disabled pseudoclass.  You should therefore provide the textfill you want for a disabled control in its .dusabled pseudoclass.